Do we need to create/use multiple profiles for various user persona ?or use 1 profile with minimum access and extend via permission set/groups?
Is profiles still significant with the concept of permission set /permission set groups getting popular ? Do we need to create/use multiple profiles for various user persona ?
Instead of assigning different profiles like standard profiles/custom profiles to users. Can we have one custom profile or Standard profile with minimum or no access and extend the features /access to users via permission set or permission set groups.
I know its a stupid questions but want to know  opinions from various experts.
For example : if there is Sales cloud user with Profile : Standard Platform User    and another Service User with Profile : Standard User .
My expectation is create a custom profile with minimum access and extend Salescloud access and service cloud access through permission sets such that there are no impacts on above 2 users. Is it possible ? or my understanding is wrong ?

The future state of Salesforce permissioning is to move away from profiles to permission sets. You still need a profile assigned to a user but the idea is to do exactly what your expectation is, create a minimum access profile and layer on permission sets for app/object/fields ect.
Salesforce was going to enforce end of life for profile permissions in Spring '26 release but that has been postponed. There is a help article describing this and the best practice links to various features.
Here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=003834041&type=1
You don't need to create multiple profiles now, you could if you want to, however, if you're just starting out your implementation then why not build for the future.

There are still a few aspects that require a profile, such as record type access and default, or page layout assignments. The latter can be avoided using dynamic forms, for those objects and contexts these are available for, but I think the former will still need a profile to achieve. The linked article does cover this, of course.
